# How to filter data If I filled (for example) only to_price?

Tags: python, django

```
if 'category' and 'something' and 'from_price' and 'to_price' in request.GET:
        category = request.GET['category']
        something = request.GET['something']
        from_price = request.GET['from_price']
        to_price = request.GET['to_price']

        d = Data.objects.filter(Q(category = category)| Q(something = something)|Q(price__gt=from_price)|Q(price__lt=to_price))
```

How to filter this data If I filled (for example) only `to_price`? (NOT all field)

My code does not work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
import operator
conds = (request.GET.get(f) for f in ('category', 'something', 'from_price', 'to_price'))
if any(conds):
    d = Data.objects.filter(
            reduce(operator.or_, 
                (Q(**{a:b}) for a,b in zip(('category', 'something', 'price__gt', 'price__lt'), filter(lambda x: x, conds)))))
```

Note that d is only available inside the `if` statement and any code after it's successful execute.

```
# or

category = request.GET.get('category')
something = request.GET.get('something')
from_price = request.GET.get('from_price')
to_price = request.GET.get('to_price')

q = Q()
if category:
    q |= Q(category=category)
if something:
    q |= Q(something=something)
if from_price:
    q |= Q(price__gt=from_price)
if to_price:
    q |= Q(price__lt=to_price)

d = Data.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: I have: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument

Comment: Do you know an easy solution?

Comment: @Mediopolis easier? in what way? If you feel the `reduce` and `zip` way is hard to read, I've added some plain and verbose code

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(1 for x in ('category', 'something', 'from_price', 'to_price') if x in request)
```

returns a number of present fields (0 to 4) You can then check whether this number is 2 or 3.